# rotate png inside uibutton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` inside a `titleView` of a UINavigationBar.  I want to rotate a downwards caret image 180 degrees every time the user taps a given button.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how can you do it using Transforms:- The code works with all the elements that inherits from UIView

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.yourButton.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

}
```

To set it back to original position:-

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
      self.yourButton.imageView?.transform = .identity)

}
```

Comment: will do when possible

Comment: @DarkInnocence You cannot accept an answer until 15 minutes have passed since the question has been posted. Please be patient.

Comment: sorry Xcoder, didn't know that.. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Looks good EXECPT the set it back to the original rotation bit is wrong. It should be `self.yourButton.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`. `180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) * 180.0` is going to give some screwy angle. Also, there's no real point setting the rotated angle to `180 * pi / 180`. Just set the angle to `CGFloat.pi`.

Comment: totally agree with you, It's just some old api's I still remember because of objc I'll edit it again.

Comment: Do you have an idea why rotating the button's 'UIImageView' by uneven angle causes warps? [Video](https://monosnap.com/file/J8iB1HHq3UecTGxvnpJYKyFNy7eFPP)